# Trouble using multicols and figures

Tags: floats, white-space, wide

I'm just learning LaTeX and experimenting with multicol and figures. Firstly I was wondering if there is a better way of inserting a wide figure than what I have been doing where I enter and exit the multicols environment eg. the figure in Task 7. Secondly, I was wondering if there is something I can do to get rid of the white space under Task 8. Here's the code I'm using and what it's producing. Thanks for your help :)

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{decay time background}
\caption{Plots removing background noise for D0 decay time.The blue histogram represents the signal only region while the orange histogram represents the background region. The red plot is the difference between the signal and the background.}
\label{fig: decay time background}
\end{figure}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\textbf{Task 8}

The known value of $0.4103 \pm 0.0010 ps$ from Particle Data Group is within 4 standard deviations of value from the fit of $\tau = 0.4141 \pm 0.0015 ps$ from Figure \ref{fig: decay time fit}. Systematic error could be due to a calibration error in the measurements of position and momentum or possibly due to interference from external magnetic fields.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{decay time fit}
\caption{Fit for decay time with $\tau = 0.4141 \pm 0.0015 ps$}
\label{fig: decay time fit}
\end{figure}

\textbf{Task 9}
```

[image: Issue at hand]

Comment: could you add a small, but compilable test file? Some classes offer full width figures.

Comment: You can use `figure*` with `multicols` for full width figures